# Type constructor with no parameters causing "Can't infer argument" error

Tags: idris

I defined a type like this:

```
data MyList a = Empty | Cons a (MyList a)
```

In Haskell, an empty `MyList` can be instantiated with `Empty`, but Idris complains:

```
> Empty
(input):Can't infer argument a to Empty
```

Why is that?

Comment: You can also say `Empty {a=Integer}`. This just means 'implicit argument a is Integer'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:set showimplicits` in the REPL helps when debugging error messages:

```
>:set showimplicits
>:t Empty
Main.Empty : {a : Type} -> Main.MyList a
```

As you can see, the type constructor has an argument and it can't infer it. If you call a function (like `Empty` is one), Idris tries to infer values for all implicit arguments. If `a` can be inferred from the context, for example by using `the (MyList Nat) Empty`, it works.

If you are explicit about the argument, it works too (and you can see a distinction between Haskell and Idris):

```
data MyList : Type -> Type where
  Empty : (a : Type) -> MyList a
  Cons : (a : Type) -> (x : a) -> MyList a -> MyList a

>Empty
Empty : (a : Type) -> MyList a
```

Idris' `a` is explicit, while in Haskell the unbound type parameter is hidden: `Empty :: MyList a`.

Comment: Thanks, I can sort of guess what `the` does from its type, but do you know where it is documented so I can read more? Also, why does the second example work as opposed to the first (mine)?

Comment: Try `:printdef the`: the implementation is just `the a = id`. So it is just `id`, but you say which type you need. Then Idris can now figure out the implicit argument of the type constructor, because it knows what `the` wants.

The only difference in the second example is that the implicit argument is now explici. It now forces you to give the wanted type, and Idris doesn't try to infer it (so won't complain). Note that `Empty` there is just a function, not a actual value like in Haskell. Also, in a real program you wouldn't need either, because the type should be clear from the context.